# asking multiplication table using random integers

Tags: java

I wrote the following code that asks the question 'How much is num1 times num2?'. However when I tried to run the java file I got no response. Can you please help me to understand what I did wrong. The code is as follows:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class MultiplyLearn{

    public void Learn(){

        Random multiple = new Random();
        Scanner input = new Scanner( System.in );
        boolean wrong = true;

        int num1 = 1 + multiple.nextInt( 9 );
        int num2 = 1 + multiple.nextInt( 9 );

        while( wrong == true ){

        askQuestion( num1, num2 );
        int answer = input.nextInt();

        if( answer == num1*num2 ){
            System.out.println( "Very Good" );
            wrong = false;
        }

        else{
            System.out.print( "No. Please try again." );
        }
        }
    }

    public String askQuestion( int x, int y ){

        return "How much is" + x + "times" + y + "?";
    }
}
```

Comment: do you have a main method in the  class?

Comment: Plus you're not printing your question... Simply returning the string will not work ;)

Answer (score 1):

Add a main method to your class

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class MultiplyLearn{

   //your actual code goes here

   public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception{
       new MultiplyLearn().Learn();
   }
}
```

so your final class will look as

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class MultiplyLearn{

    public void Learn(){

        Random multiple = new Random();
        Scanner input = new Scanner( System.in );
        boolean wrong = true;

        int num1 = 1 + multiple.nextInt( 9 );
        int num2 = 1 + multiple.nextInt( 9 );

        while( wrong == true ){

        askQuestion( num1, num2 );
        int answer = input.nextInt();

        if( answer == num1*num2 ){
            System.out.println( "Very Good" );
            wrong = false;
        }

        else{
            System.out.print( "No. Please try again." );
        }
        }
    }

    public String askQuestion( int x, int y ){

        return "How much is" + x + "times" + y + "?";
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception{
       new MultiplyLearn().Learn();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class MultiplyLearn {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        MultiplyLearn driver = new MultiplyLearn();
        //driver.askQuestion(2, 4);
        driver.Learn();

    }

    public void Learn(){

        Random multiple = new Random();
        Scanner input = new Scanner( System.in );
        boolean wrong = true;

        int num1 = 1 + multiple.nextInt( 9 );
        int num2 = 1 + multiple.nextInt( 9 );

        while( wrong == true ){

        // ISSUE: The returned value needs to be printed out. The program was waiting for input and hence it did not proceed from there(No O/P). I have corrected it.
        System.out.println(askQuestion( num1, num2 ));
        int answer = input.nextInt();

        if( answer == num1*num2 ){
            System.out.println( "Very Good" );
            wrong = false;
        }

        else{
            System.out.print( "No. Please try again." );
        }
        }
    }

    public String askQuestion( int x, int y ){

        return "How much is" + x + "times" + y + "?";
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you all for your responses. In my initial code I forgot to mention that it was a separate class and that I was implementing the main method in another class. However, I understand now that I should have printed out the return values, which is why I got a blank screen. I have done the corrections and it worked really well. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you need:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class MultiplyLearn{

    public void learn(){

        Random multiple = new Random();
        Scanner input = new Scanner( System.in );
        boolean wrong = true;

        int num1 = 1 + multiple.nextInt( 9 );
        int num2 = 1 + multiple.nextInt( 9 );

        while(wrong){
            System.out.println("How much is " + num1 + " times " + num2 + "?");
            int answer = input.nextInt();

            if( answer == num1*num2 ){
                System.out.println( "Very Good" );
                wrong = false;
            }

        else{
            System.out.print( "No. Please try again." );
        }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        MultiplyLearn learner = new MultiplyLearn();

        learner.Learn();
    }
```

A few points:

- Naming conventions suggest methods should start in lower case
- I don't see the point in having a seperate method simply for asking the question

Answer (score 0):

Use naming conventions first : http://java.about.com/od/javasyntax/a/nameconventions.htm
So name Learn() function as learn().
Then you have to start the project from a static function. 
So if you want to start project from learn() function you need to make it static(but you need to make other function also static in this case), or if you just want to use that function you need to write a static main function(preffered in this case).

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class MultiplyLearn{

    public static void main(String args[]){
        MultiplyLearn multiplyLearn = new MultiplyLearn();
        multiplyLearn.learn();
    }

    public void learn(){

        Random multiple = new Random();
        Scanner input = new Scanner( System.in );
        boolean wrong = true;

        int num1 = 1 + multiple.nextInt( 9 );
        int num2 = 1 + multiple.nextInt( 9 );

        while( wrong == true ){

        askQuestion( num1, num2 );
        int answer = input.nextInt();

        if( answer == num1*num2 ){
            System.out.println( "Very Good" );
            wrong = false;
        }

        else{
            System.out.print( "No. Please try again." );
        }
        }
    }

    public String askQuestion( int x, int y ){

        return "How much is" + x + "times" + y + "?";
    }
}
```